# Set parameter to file

Tags: parameters, vbscript, batch-file

Can you help?  I Do you know how automatic modify .rcq file  ? VBS?

```
           Structure file post.rcq:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rest-client version="2.3.3"><request><http-version>1.1</http-version>

<URL>http://bm.com/opr-console/rest/9.10/event_list/9752951c-0392-71e1-01a3-ac10016b0000</URL>

<method>PUT</method><auth-methods>DIGEST</auth-methods>
<auth-preemptive>true</auth-preemptive><auth-username>admin</auth-username>
<auth-password>rO0ABXQABWFkbWlu</auth-password>
<body content-type="application/xml" charset="UTF-8">&lt;event xmlns="http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model"&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;state&gt;closed&lt;/state&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;severity&gt;normal&lt;/severity&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;/event&gt;</body></request></rest-client>
```

How set parametre 
(Example:1722951c-0392-71e1-01a3-ac10016b0000) 
to .rcq file in  http://bm.com/opr-console/rest/9.10/event_list/...

Comment: I quite don't understand your question.

Comment: Udo: I think they want to refer to a different resource in the URL element by replacing the hex stuff at the end with something else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7955959/69820

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this with a batch file (for several reasons). From VBScript you can use the MSXML ActiveX object to parse the XML, modify the URL (using string functions) and write it back to disk.