# Regular Expressions in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, replace, pattern-matching

How to save all text with replaced text.
 At now save only replaced text

I want to change only 9752951c-0392-71e1-01a3- ac10016b0000 in txt
1.txt

```
  text ...
        <URL>http://bs.com/opr-console/rest/9.10/event_list/9752951c-0392-71e1-01a3- ac10016b0000</URL>        
           <method>PUT</method>
            <auth-methods>DIGEST</auth-methods>
            <auth-preemptive>true</auth-preemptive>
            <auth-username>admin</auth-username> 
            <auth-password>rO0ABXQABWFkbWlu</auth-
          .....bla-bla-la..
```

vbs script:

```
Dim objExec, objShell, objWshScriptExec, objStdOut, objArgs, ReplaceWith  
Const ForReading = 1  
Const ForWriting = 2  
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments  
strID = Trim(objArgs(0))  
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")  
objRegEx.Pattern = "^<URL>http://bsmgw.bms.consulting.com/opr-console/rest/9.10/event_list/"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test\1\1.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
    Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each strMatch In colMatches   
            Wscript.Echo strSearchString

            st = Mid(strSearchString, 71, 36)
            WScript.Echo st 
            strNewFileName = Replace(strSearchString, st, strID)
        Wscript.Echo strNewFileName
        objFile.Write
        Next
    End If 
Loop 
objFile.Close  
objFile.Close 
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would make changes to your file using an XML parser instead:

```
' load the document into an object
Dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc.async = false
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmldoc.load "C:\test\1\1.txt"

' get the URL node (look up XPath - i'm assuming that there is a single node called URL)
dim urlnode: set urlnode = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//URL")
' replace the innerText of the URL node with your replacement text
urlnode.text = strID

'save your document
xmldoc.Save "C:\test\1\2.txt"
```